# Advice for displaying image in MVC using inline style

Tags: model-view-controller, view, inline

I am new to MVC, so please forgive me! I have the following line in my
Views/Home/Index.cshtml file:

```
<div class="grid-content" style="background-image: url('~/Content/pics/mypic.jpg');">
```

(The _Layout.cshtml renders it using the standard RenderBody() call.)

But it will not display the pic. If I replace the path with a full qualified path to an internet pic, it will work. It won't work with the above syntax.

It seems to me that it has to do with the multiple uses of single/double quotes, maybe.

Is there a way for this to work? I have yet to learn how to make use of Url.Content, or some other helper method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `url()` you pass is a path to the resource from your web server, either relative to the calling page or an absolute URL.

The example you have provided looks like a *file-system path*, not a URL that your web server understands, which is why fully-qualified URLs to an "internet image" work.

Your document is stored in `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`. If the image is stored in the same folder , then simply change it to `url('mypic.jpg')`. If not, adjust accordingly.

Change the path from `~/Content/pics/mypic.jpg` to something that is relative to the document you are serving. For example, if the HTML

(Yes, URLs can contain tildes, but generally they designate "what follows is a system username", like `/~Coreysan/Content/pics/mypic.jpg`, which would direct your web server to find your `~/<whatever your web server folder is>/Content/...` resource).

Comment: Thank you @MSanford for your insight. I placed the pic in the local folder with Index.cshtml, and then changed the div to read: <div class="grid-content" style="background-image: url('mypic.jpg');">    However, it still does not show the pic. Just to be sure, I retyped the internet location, and it did work. So I'm baffled!

Comment: I use FireFox browser for Windows 10, so I use the built-in inspector, if that's what you mean. WHen I view the line after rendering, it says <div class="grid-content" style="background-image: url(mypic.jpg);">  And I have the jpg in the same folder as index.cshtml. Additionally, when I'm editing the code, I can hover over the namer of the jpg and I can see the preview pane quite nicely, so it does see the file.